# Flex 4 compatible with Flash Player 9?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flash

Could you confirm me that:

- **Flex 4** is compatible and only compatible with **Flash 10**
- **Flex 3** is compatible and only compatible with **Flash 9 & 10**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Flex 4 requires Flash player 10](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2696120)

Excerpts from the linked page:

> you can open the `<Flex SDK>/framework/flex-config.xml` file for an SDK build and it should tell you what the minimum required Player version is for that particular SDK:

```
<flex-config>
  <!-- Specifies the minimum player version that will run the compiled SWF. -->
  <target-player>10.0.0</target-player>

  <!-- other tags -->
</flex-config>
```

You can use this to find the min-version required for Flex-3 also; This post on SO says you need [Flash Player 9 or above to run it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541427/what-flash-player-version-is-required-by-simple-flex-3-apps).

Comment: Thanks for your references.

We are starting a flex project. But all our clients have Flash 9.
We want to be sure that our project will be supported by our client?
Which way will assure us a compatibility with Flash 9?
Starting a Flex 3 Project? Or Starting a Flex 4 project with a "potential Flash 9 compatibility option"?

Thx

Comment: @Eric If the client is not interested in updating their Flash player to 10 (why wouldn't they - it is free, fast and more secure; always keep browser plugins up-to-date; especially Flash), you're gonna have to stick to Flex-3. Having both Flex-4 and Flex-3 versions is possible, but maintaining the two can be hard. It depends on the project, if the i-wont-update-my-plugin clients are really important to you, you should go the hard way. If you can convince them to update, use Flex-3; it will run in flash 9 and 10 or any upcoming versions.

Comment: there are many environments where upgrading is not feasible.  Large corporate networks and universities often have systems locked down to prevent users from upgrading themselves and commonly lag behind latest available software, even when free and more secure.  Hospitals are also usually very problematic in this area.

Comment: That's true, my client is a large company, still using Internet Explorer 6. Thx to both of you :)